# .copychart from Excel to Word errors unless both applications are visible

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, ms-word, word-2010

Using `.copychart` in pasting from Excel to Word errors in my code below. If both applications are visible, as I've had them while programming, then it works well.

Is there a way to hide the applications (let them run in the background) and still use `.copychart` or do I need a different solution?

I am only showing a small parts of the code, as the entire module is quite large. Here is where I get the error on the `.copypicture` line:

```
'Copy charts to Worddocument
Dim cht1 As Chart, cht2 As Chart, cht3 As Chart

With tbl2
    cht1.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
    With .cell(4, 1).Tables(1).cell(2, 1).Range
        .Paste 'Paste NetRevenue Graph
        .InlineShapes(1).ScaleWidth = 100
    End With
End With
```

Comment: Have you tried it using `Appearance:= xlPrinter` Maybe using xlScreen is creating the error because Excel cannot work out how the chart looks on the screen when it is not visible.

Comment: @ChippsLetten ´Apperance:=xlPrinter´ was a good suggestion. However, it ended up still trowing an error. I did notice however that I was wrong to say that both applications need to be visible. Only Excel needs to be visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few options you can try:

For **Word**:

If you have

```
Dim wordApp As Word.Application
Dim wordDoc As Word.Document
```

1.

```
wordApp.Visible = False
'...copy chart
wordApp.Visible = True
```

2.

```
wordDoc.Windows(1).WindowState = wdWindowStateMinimize
'...copy chart
wordDoc.Windows(1).WindowState = wdWindowStateMaximize   'or wdWindowStateNormal
```

.

For **Excel**:

1.

```
Application.Visible = False
'...copy chart
Application.Visible = True
```

2.

```
ActiveWorkbook.Windows(1).WindowState = xlMinimized
'...copy chart
ActiveWorkbook.Windows(1).WindowState = xlMaximized
```

3.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'...copy chart
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, but if I do that, I gain nothing in execution efficiency. Essentially, this is what I currently have.

Comment: So is your question "how to hide the applications in order to eliminate an error" or "how to make the code more efficient"? Also, you may not realize it for 1 or 2 operations, but hiding the applications during processing improves performance significantly when working with hundreds of files

Comment: My question is how to let the code run totally in the background without having to show the applications (the whole code starts execution in MS Access). The point of doing that is that the code will run more efficiently. Your suggestions do in fact improve performance, I realize this, but I'm looking for a solution that would do away entirely with having to see Excel or Word. In any case, I appreciate your effort in trying to help find a solution!

Comment: i'm using your suggestion now... can't find another solution :- ). so plus one to you and the answer marked as correct.

Comment: in a way I wish I understood better how else this can be optimized (I'm very focused on improving performance as much as possible). sometimes we may have to compromise, but I'm glad it's a bit useful

Comment: same here... if I do happen to come across an answer i'll come back here and post it so you see it! cheers!

Comment: I just saw this answer on MSDN... very similar problem but a different solution. In case you are interested: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg508924.aspx

Comment: Interesting: they're expecting errors when deleting previous word charts (wdDoc.InlineShapes(1).Delete). The Err object can provide more details if you add it to the Watch window. Thanks

Comment: They're not providing the best solution relative to the error part, probably because they want to focus on copying the chart: they know it's very probable that the code will be attempting to delete an object that may not exist (no previous chart). The proper way to deal with this specific situation is to not cause the error in the first place, something like "If wdDoc.InlineShapes.Count > 0 Then" select the first one and delete it. But the complexity comes when you have multiple previous charts and you'll have to identify the proper one to be deleted\replaced